# Comparing values within the same dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there anyway to compare values within the same column of a pandas DataFrame?

The task at hand is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0,-5,2,3,-3,-4,-4,-2,-1,5,6,7,3,-1]});
```

I need to find the maximum time (in indices) consecutive +/- values appear (Equivalently checking consecutive values because the sign can be encoded by True/False). The above data should yield 5 because there are 5 consecutive negative integers [-3,-4,-4,-2,-1]

If possible, I was hoping to avoid using a loop because the number of data points in the column may very well exceed millions in order.

I've tried using `data.A.rolling()` and it's variants, but can't seem to figure out any possible way to do this in a vectorized way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a NumPy approach that computes the max interval lengths for the positive and negative values -

```
def max_interval_lens(arr):
    # Store mask of positive values
    pos_mask = arr>=0

    # Get indices of shifts
    idx = np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(pos_mask[1:] != pos_mask[:-1])+1, arr.size]

    # Return max of intervals
    lens = np.diff(idx)
    s = int(pos_mask[0])
    maxs = [0,0]    
    if len(lens)==1:
        maxs[1-s] = lens[0]
    else:
        maxs = lens[1-s::2].max(), lens[s::2].max() 

    return maxs # Positive, negative max lens
```

Sample run -

```
In [227]: data
Out[227]: 
    A
0   0
1  -5
2   2
3   3
4  -3
5  -4
6  -4
7  -2
8  -1
9   5
10  6
11  7
12  3
13 -1

In [228]: max_interval_lens(data['A'].values)
Out[228]: (4, 5)
```

Comment: Wow, that was seriously creative ... thanks a ton! I was getting stuck at how to isolate switch in signs from only - to +. The reshape bit helped. Thanks, this was awesomely helpful :)

Comment: @AtulyaUrankar Changed a bit there to simplify, that also avoids the reshaping.